# fastest way to filter row and column in R

Tags: r, matrix, filtering

I have a big matrix (x) with about 1'500'000 rows and 7000 columns. I would like to filter out with R:

- all the rows having less than 5 columns with a value greater than 1;
- all columns having less than 100 rows with a value greater than 1.

I tried the following code but it takes too long to run (it is stuck on the first command):

```
x_rows <- apply(x, 1, function(y) sum(y>1))
x_column <- apply(x, 2, function(y) sum(y>1))
x_f <- x[x_rows>5, x_column>100]
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

Try `rowSums` and `colSums`:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- matrix(rnorm(150000*7000), 150000, 7000)

system.time({
  x_rows <- rowSums(x>1)
  x_column <- colSums(x>1)
  x_f <- x[x_rows>5, x_column>100]
})
#       User      System verstrichen 
#     10.534       1.620      12.158
```